# Replace module to remove everything starting with a string to the end of file

Tags: regex, replace, ansible

I need to remove text from a file starting with a particular string — `control_center_basic_users:` — until the end of file

```yaml
control_center_basic_users:
  admin:
    principal: admin
    password: ''
    roles: admin
```

I have tried the below (found on another question regarding the end of the file)

```yaml
- name: cleanup the file 
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /tmp/kafka_users_test.yaml
    regexp: '^(\s*)control_center_basic_users:[^[]+'
    replace: ''
    backup: yes
```

But that doesn't work. I have not found a way that would include everything after and all the way through the end of the file.
How do I write my regular expression to include everything until the end of file?

I also tried `(.*?)((control_center_basic_users:)|$)` which identifies the `control_center_basic_users:` and the last line but not the complete block.
How can I achieve that?

Format of *kafka_users_test.yaml* - masterkey value is changed, so this is not the actual value, just kept the same format for that value.

```yaml
secrets_protection_masterkey: XUasdfghjklopiuytrewqazxcvbnmkljhdsetbfsd+E=
sasl_plain_users:

  user1_producer:
    principal: user1_producer
    password: user1-secret
  user2_consumer:
    principal: user2_consumer
    password: user2-secret
  user3_producer:
    principal: user3_producer
    password: user3-producer-secret
  user4_consumer:
    principal: user4_consumer
    password: user4-consumer-secret
  test_newuser:
    principal: test_newuser
    password: newuser
  DATA_25739:
    principal: DATA_25739
    password: DATA_25739_pw
control_center_basic_users:
  admin:
    principal: admin
    password: ''
    roles: admin
```

Also, I want to get rid of the empty line in below

```yaml
sasl_plain_users:

  user1_producer:
```

I tried this, but that doesn't work

```yaml
- name: remove empty line from yaml
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /software/confluent-7.3/secrets/kafka_users_test.yaml
    state: absent 
    regexp: '^$'
```

Comment: `[\S\s]*` perhaps? or you may need to include newline `[\S\s\n]*`

Comment: If `control_center_basic_users` is the only element you want to remove, you could also user the YAML capacities of Ansible. Could you share a more accurate YAML structure of `kafka_users_test.yaml` — blanking values if you must?

Comment: Added the actual file format

Comment: @Nick - Thanks.  I tested the above - `[\S\s]*` - this way `regexp: '((control_center_basic_users:)[\S\s]*|$)'`.  That worked.

Comment: @adbdkb good to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it, since you are dealing with a YAML file is to

1. `slurp` it, so you can manage the file content as a YAML structure
2. reject the attribute `control_center_basic_users` out of the dictionary, helped with a pair `dict2items` / `items2dict`
3. dump it back to the file with `to_nice_yaml` and its `sort_keys=False` option, otherwise the YAML dumper would also re-sort your dictionary keys alphabetically — doing this will also get rid of any white line, as you also mentioned it

So, with the two tasks:

```yaml
- slurp:
    src: /tmp/kafka_users_test.yaml
  register: kafka_users

- copy:
    content: >-
      {{
        kafka_users.content
          | b64decode
          | from_yaml
          | dict2items
          | rejectattr('key', '==', 'control_center_basic_users')
          | items2dict
          | to_nice_yaml(sort_keys=False)
      }}
    dest: /tmp/kafka_users_test.yaml
```

Your file */tmp/kafka_users_test.yaml* would end up looking like this:

```yaml
secrets_protection_masterkey: XUasdfghjklopiuytrewqazxcvbnmkljhdsetbfsd+E=
sasl_plain_users:
    user1_producer:
        principal: user1_producer
        password: user1-secret
    user2_consumer:
        principal: user2_consumer
        password: user2-secret
    user3_producer:
        principal: user3_producer
        password: user3-producer-secret
    user4_consumer:
        principal: user4_consumer
        password: user4-consumer-secret
    test_newuser:
        principal: test_newuser
        password: newuser
    DATA_25739:
        principal: DATA_25739
        password: DATA_25739_pw
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the file for testing

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.yaml
var1: foo
var2: bar
control_center_basic_users:
  - user1
  - user2
```

- The parameter [regexp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-regexp) says:

> The `.` special character matches any character **except newlines** ...

- The parameter [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-replace) says:

> If not set, matches are **removed entirely**.

This means that the below regex matches a single line only

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.yaml
        regexp: '^\s*control_center_basic_users:.*$'
```

gives (running with options --check --diff)

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/test.yaml
+++ after: /tmp/test.yaml
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 var1: foo
 var2: bar
-control_center_basic_users:
+
   - user1
   - user2
```

---

Note: The line wasn't removed completely because of the regexp not matching the trailing newline. In other words, the  newline is left. This is the reason why you see the empty line.

---

Q: ***"Remove text from a file starting with a particular string `control_center_basic_users:` until the end of file."***

A: If you want to select the rest till the end of the file replace `.` by `[\S\s]` (credit @Nick) that matches any character including a newline. For example,

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.yaml
        regexp: '^\s*control_center_basic_users:[\S\s]*$'
```

does what you want

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/test.yaml
+++ after: /tmp/test.yaml
@@ -1,5 +1,2 @@
 var1: foo
 var2: bar
-control_center_basic_users:
-  - user1
-  - user2
```

---

Note: The lines were removed completely because of the regexp  matching also the trailing newlines. This is the reason why you don't see any empty lines.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.yaml
        regexp: '^\s*control_center_basic_users:.*$'
      tags: t1

    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.yaml
        regexp: '^\s*control_center_basic_users:[\S\s]*$'
      tags: t2
```

Comment: Both the answers worked.  Could pick only one, so picked the one above.